How does TorchServe preprocesses the payload before being fed to the PyTorch Model
I am trying to understand how TorchServe processing of data works before is actually fed to the Handler and ultimately PyTorch Model. In the BaseHanlder() class, which is the the default handler I think, this is the implementation of the preprocess() method, the one that process the data before it gets to the model.
 def preprocess(self, data):
        """
        Preprocess function to convert the request input to a tensor(Torchserve supported format).
        The user needs to override to customize the pre-processing

        Args :
            data (list): List of the data from the request input.

        Returns:
            tensor: Returns the tensor data of the input
        """

        return torch.as_tensor(data, device=self.device)

torch.as_tensor() can only take as input a list, numpy array or tensor. So, this lets me to think that before data gets to the Handler the framework must do some type of preprocessing where it parses the json string payload. Now, the json string payloaad is like a dicationary right?. So, my question would be, does TorchServe converts the payload into a Python dictionary and then parses it to get a list that can be then processed by the Handler. Is there any documentation link? or if you have an answer to my question would really appreciate it (what is really happening in the backend). Thanks a lot in advance.
Also, if you have ever worked or know how would this be affected if your are hosting your model in VertexAi for example. I guess VertexAI is realling using the TorchServe Framework??
